# javascript localstorage two div

Tags: javascript, session, caching, local-storage, session-storage

I have 2 blocks on my website, I want to display the last div that was active when the page was refreshed

I need your help because I have no knowledge

event 1
    click to show second div

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">click and show other div</div>
```

event 2
    click to show second div

```
<div style="visibility:visible">click and show other div</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stak Overflow. Please try to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking a good question needs some time and effort.

Comment: to click on one to hide and show the other

Answer (score 0):

You should do this using some JavaScript. I am trying to provide you with a simplified snippet:

```js
function myToggle(e) {
  var id = e.target.id;
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (id === "btn1") {
    var y = document.getElementById("btn2");
  } else {
    var y = document.getElementById("btn1");
  }
  x.style.display = "none";
  y.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="myToggle(event)">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="myToggle(event)">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: I don't want a button, the last event needs to be remembered

Comment: change the code snippet into your needs

Comment: will not change when the page is refreshed. both appeared at the same time, there is an error in the code